# How to handle column names not supported by sqldf in R

Tags: r, sqldf

I've a data frame where some of the column names are of the format . format. For ex: Company.1
when i'm using that column in a sqldf function it throws an error

```
data=sqldf(select Company.1 from test)
Error in sqliteExecStatement(con, statement, bind.data) : 
RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: near ".1": syntax error)
```

Any workaround so that i can use the column name as it is?

Answer (score 5):

The dot has another meaning in SQL (e.g., separating table name from column name) and 
is replaced by an underscore before sending the data to SQLite.

```
library(sqldf)
test <- data.frame( "Company.1" = 1:10 )
sqldf( 'SELECT Company_1 FROM test' )
```

Comment: Added a year later. Note that the latest version of RSQLite no longer replaces dots with underscores.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck how to handle such a situation then?

Comment: Put the name in double quotes: `sqldf( 'SELECT "Company.1" FROM test' )` .  This also works: `sqldf( 'SELECT [Company.1] FROM test' )`

Comment: I think [Company.1] is safer than "Company.1" because if you misspell "Company.1" you will not get a column not found error, it will just be interpreted as a string (and in SQL "stringname1" < 5 is a valid comparison). OTOH if you misspell [Company.1] you will get a column not found error.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is about the `.` in your column name, if you change it to `Company_1` it works:

```
data = sqldf("select Company_1 from test")
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution for the latest update of `sqldf` is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28864072/4786271)

> We only need to write the SQL statement between single quotes, and the
>   column names including dots between double quotes or
>   backticks/backquotes interchangeably.